# Query GSI for a list of ids in dynamoDB using spring-data-dynamodb

Tags: spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamoDB with a GSI with a hashKey and a rangeKey.
I want to query the GSI for a list of hashKey-rangeKey.

For example,
productKey = 123,456,789
product = productA

I tried a method like this,
findByProductRefKeyInAndProduct(List productKeys, String product);

However, this does a scan on the table instead of a query.

Is it even possible to query the table for this type of request. I believe it should be, but I am not able to find the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dynamoDB does not support querying for multiple values over a GSI in a single query. The recommended approach is to query for each value parallelly - [DynamoDB batch execute QueryRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953783/dynamodb-batch-execute-queryrequests)